# SED delete (inclusive) between 2 patterns only if 3rd pattern present

Tags: shell, sed

I'll keep this short.  I want to use sed to delete sets of text in a file.  Basically here is an example of what I have:

```
textbefore
PATTERN 1
  text1
    PATTERN 3
  text2
PATTERN 2
PATTERN 1
  text3
   text4
  text5
PATTERN 2
textafter
```

What I want to happen is to PATTERN 1 through PATTERN 2 (inclusive) but ONLY if it contains PATTERN3 between the two.

This is basically what I want to see:

```
textbefore
PATTERN 1
  text3
   text4
  text5
PATTERN 2
textafter
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Works with GNU sed, at least.

```
sed '/PATTERN 1/{:a;/PATTERN 2/bb;N;ba;:b;/PATTERN 3/d;}' file
```

with commentary:

```sed
#!/usr/bin/sed
/PATTERN 1/ {        # when start pattern is seen
  :a
  /PATTERN 2/ bb     # goto "b" if end pattern seen
  N                  # append next line to pattern space
  ba                 # and goto "a"
  :b
  /PATTERN 3/ d      # if this "block" contains patt, delete
}
```

Comment: I get `sed: 1: "/PATTERN 1/ {:a; /PATTE ...": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)` when I run this.

Comment: Are you on OSX or BSD? add a `;` before each `}`

Comment: FreeBSD 10.1.  I added `;` before each of the two `}`s.  Same error. Are you sure you can put a label inside curly braces?

Comment: Hmm.  Yes, if I expand the `{bb}` on to multiple lines.  But there's gotta be a way to onelineify this, hasn't there?

Comment: Maybe the braces require more than one command. Try the updated version now

Comment: No dice.  But I'm giving up on this one.

Comment: Updated version not working for me on OSX.  Still getting the unexpected EOF error

Comment: Don't have a mac to test. Check the man page to see what the problem is: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html

Answer (score 0):

If you like to try `awk` this should do:

```
awk '/PATTERN 1/ {s=1} s {a[++c]=$0} /PATTERN 3/ {p=1} /PATTERN 2/ {if (!p) for (i=1;i<=c;i++) print a[i];delete a;s=p=c=0;next} !s' file
textbefore
PATTERN 1
  text3
   text4
  text5
PATTERN 2
textafter
```

---

How it works:

```
awk '
/PATTERN 1/ {s=1}                   # If pattern "1" is found set flag "s"
s           {a[++c]=$0}             # If flag "s" is set store the row in array "a"
/PATTERN 3/ {p=1}                   # If pattern "3" is found set flag "p"
/PATTERN 2/ {                       # If pattern "2" is found
            if (!p)                 # Test if flag "p" is not set
                for (i=1;i<=c;i++)  # Loop "c" number of times
                    print a[i]      # Print data in array "a"
            delete a                # Delete array "a"
            s=p=c=0                 # Reset flag and counters
            next}                   # Skip to next line
!s                                  # If flag "s" is not set, print the line
' file                              # Read the file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `perl` we have advantage of using lookarounds in regex:

```
perl -00 -pe 's/(?s)PATTERN 1(?=.*?PATTERN 3)((?!PATTERN [12]).)*PATTERN 2\R+//g' file
textbefore    
PATTERN 1
  text3
   text4
  text5
PATTERN 2
textafter
```

**RegEx Explanation:**

```
?s                   # to make dot match newlines also
PATTERN 1            # to match literal PATTERN 1
(?=.*?PATTERN 3)     # lookahead to make sure PATTERN 3 comes before the
                     # next PATTERN 2
((?!PATTERN [12]).)* # negative lookahead to make sure PATTERN 1 or PATTERN 2
                     # isn't matched before next PATTERN 2
PATTERN 2            # to match literal PATTERN 2
\R+                  # to match 1 or more new lines
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but a little explanation of the regex would help.

Comment: You want `\R+` don't you?

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ gawk -vRS='PATTERN 2' '{ORS=(sub(/(^|\n)PATTERN 1.*PATTERN 3.*/,"")?"":RT)}1' file
textbefore
PATTERN 1
  text3
   text4
  text5
PATTERN 2
textafter
```

or with any awk:

```
$ awk '
    { buf = buf $0 RS }
    /PATTERN 2/ { sub(/PATTERN 1.*PATTERN 3.*/,"",buf); printf "%s",buf; buf="" }
    END { printf "%s",buf }
' file
textbefore
PATTERN 1
  text3
   text4
  text5
PATTERN 2
textafter
```

Comment: Thanks Ed.  This is what eventually worked for me.  If the pattern example wasn't obvious I was just looking for a quick and dirty way to do some systematic deletions in some xml files.  Much greedier than sed system usage wise but it only needs to be run every now and then so it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/PATTERN 1/,/PATTERN 2/!b;/PATTERN 1/h;//!H;/PATTERN 2/!d;g;/PATTERN 3/d' file
```

Treat lines not between the first two patterns as normal. For lines between the first two patterns, save those lines in the hold space and delete them except if the line is the second of the two patterns. For the last line between the two patterns, check if the third pattern is present and if it is delete those lines otherwise print as normal.